# How to efficiently find the inverse intersection between two large dataframes with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, bigdata, intersection

I am trying to find the inverse intersection between two **large** dataframes.
I got it to work with the code snipped hereafter. Unfortunately, this approach is "too slow" on large dataframes as is further described below. Can you think of a quicker way to compute this outcome?

```
import pandas as pd

df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [8, 2, 2],
                     'b': [0, 1, 3],
                     'c': [0, 2, 2],
                     'd': [0, 2, 2],
                     'e': [0, 2, 2]})

df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [8, 2, 2, 2, 8, 2],
                     'b': [0, 1, 1, 6, 0, 1],
                     'c': [0, 3, 2, 2, 0, 2],
                     'd': [0, 4, 2, 2, 0, 4],
                     'e': [0, 1, 2, 2, 0, 2]})

l_columns = ['a','b','e']

def df_drop_df(df_1, df_2, l_columns):
    """
    Eliminates all equal rows present in dataframe 1 (df_1) from dataframe 2 (df_2) depending on a subset of columns (l_columns)

    :param df_1: dataframe that defines which rows to be removed
    :param df_2: dataframe that is reduced
    :param l_columns: list of column names, present in df_1 and df_2, that is used for the comparison

    :return df_out: final dataframe
    """
    df_1r = df_1[l_columns]
    df_2r = df_2[l_columns].reset_index()

    df_m = pd.merge(df_1r, df_2r, on=l_columns, how='inner')
    row_indexes_m = df_m['index'].to_list()

    row_indexes_df_2 = df_2.index.to_list()
    row_indexes_out = [x for x in row_indexes_df_2 if x not in row_indexes_m]

    df_out = df_2.loc[row_indexes_out]
    return df_out
```

Giving the following correct result:

```
#row_indexes_out = [1,3]

df_output = df_drop_df(df_1, df_2, l_columns)
df_output

({'a': [2, 2],
  'b': [1, 6],
  'c': [3, 2],
  'd': [4, 2],
  'e': [1, 2]})
```

However, for the actual application, the size of the dataframes has the following dimensions, which takes roughly 30min to compute on my local machine:

| variable | shape |
| --- | --- |
| df1 | (3300,77) |
| df2 | (642000,77) |
| l_columns | list 12 |
| df_out | (611000,77) |

(This means that each row present in df_1 is roughly 10 times in df_2)

Can you think of a quicker way to compute this outcome?

Comment: Are you looking for the complement of the intersection of this two dataframes with respect to the common columns?

Comment: Yes, the complement of the intersection is more correct than how I called it (inverse intersection). What takes so long should be the merging step and not the inversion of the problem, right?

It is not just all common columns, but specific columns (which both dataframes need to have in common.)

Comment: Are you entirely sure that what you are getting is actually the complement of the intersection given the columns you are using as keys? I get an additional row and I only use the definition of the complement.

Comment: Can you post what you are doing? The outcome should be line 1 and 3 as the two dataframes are compared on columns a, b and e

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try substituting the following lines:

```
row_indexes_df_2 = df_2.index.to_list()
row_indexes_out = [x for x in row_indexes_df_2 if x not in row_indexes_m]

df_out = df_2.loc[row_indexes_out]
```

by the tilde operator:

```
df_out = df_2.loc[~df_2.index.isin(row_indexes_m)]
```

It should considerably reduce the time.

Comment: This step takes now only 0.5s on my local machine on the large dataframe.